# How to add a condition in split apply combine and repeat solution on each row?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, split-apply-combine

I have the following `pandas` dataframe `df`:

```
cluster   tag   amount   name
1         0     200      Michael        
2         1     1200     John        
2         1     900      Daniel        
2         0     3000     David        
2         0     600      Jonny        
3         0     900      Denisse        
3         1     900      Mike        
3         1     3000     Kely        
3         0     2000     Devon
```

What I need to do is add another column in `df` that writes for each `row`, the `name` (from the name column) that has the highest `amount` where the `tag` is 1. In other words, the solution looks like this:

```
cluster   tag   amount   name     highest_amount
1         0     200      Michael  NaN      
2         1     1200     John     John   
2         1     900      Daniel   John     
2         0     3000     David    John    
2         0     600      Jonny    John    
3         0     900      Denisse  Kely      
3         1     900      Mike     Kely   
3         1     3000     Kely     Kely   
3         0     2000     Devon    Kely
```

I've tried something like this:

```
df.group('clusters')['name','amount'].transform('max')[df['tag']==1]
```

but the problem with this is that the name does note repeat on every row. It will look like this:

```
cluster   tag   amount   name     highest_amount
1         0     200      Michael  NaN      
2         1     1200     John     John   
2         1     900      Daniel   John     
2         0     3000     David    NaN    
2         0     600      Jonny    NaN    
3         0     900      Denisse  NaN      
3         1     900      Mike     Kely   
3         1     3000     Kely     Kely   
3         0     2000     Devon    NaN
```

Can someone please let me know how to add a condition with split apply combine, and have the solution repeated on each row?

Comment: I'm not sure that's valid pandas syntax? I can't test - does this work, as-posted?

Comment: @roganjosh yes, it will work, it's just like doing df then applying a filer

Comment: with the `.` in `df.group('clusters').['name','amount']`? If so, I've learned something new.

Comment: @roganjosh ups, my mistake, without the ".".  I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a two-stage process. First calculate a mapping series, then map by cluster:

```
s = df.query('tag == 1')\
      .sort_values('amount', ascending=False)\
      .drop_duplicates('cluster')\
      .set_index('cluster')['name']

df['highest_name'] = df['cluster'].map(s)

print(df)

   cluster  tag  amount     name highest_name
0        1    0     200  Michael          NaN
1        2    1    1200     John         John
2        2    1     900   Daniel         John
3        2    0    3000    David         John
4        2    0     600    Jonny         John
5        3    0     900  Denisse         Kely
6        3    1     900     Mike         Kely
7        3    1    3000     Kely         Kely
8        3    0    2000    Devon         Kely
```

---

If you want to use `groupby`, here's one way:

```
def func(x):
    names = x.query('tag == 1').sort_values('amount', ascending=False)['name']
    return names.iloc[0] if not names.empty else np.nan

df['highest_name'] = df['cluster'].map(df.groupby('cluster').apply(func))
```

Comment: this works. I am wondering however if there's a way to do it with group and transform. Do you know if that's even possible?

Comment: @callmeGuy, I added a `groupby` solution, doesn't use `transform` though.